# Trying to switch between two trainers on one account

Tags: pokemon-go

For the last few years my sons have been playing Pokemon Go as different trainers, but we have had one account (one son uses my phone while the other uses my wife's). They have different trainer names and have been playing unique games. But we just recently got logged out, and now when I log back in, it immediately goes to my younger son's trainer. How can I help my older son get to his trainer?

Comment: Hi Jason, what sort of phone (iPhone, Android) and what account were you using to log into Pokemon Go (Facebook, Google, Apple, or Pokemon Trainer Club?) Chances are the Pokemon Go account for your older son's trainer is attached to a different type of account (say, Google), while your younger one's trainer is attached to let's say, Apple. Thus if you sign in the Pokemon Go using Apple on both devices, you'll only get your younger son's account. Does that make sense?